# continue user activity not called

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use Associated Domains to open custom links in my app in order to verify users email (Done with Firebase). The links sends fine and upon clicking on it the user does get taken to the app, however `application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool` does not get called in my AppDelegate. I have no idea why. Since I'm developing in iOS 13 I though perhaps the function had been renamed, but as far as I can tell that's not the case. I did make sure to return true from application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.